# sampling distribution question

Tags: statistics, sampling

Need clarification on a binomial sample example:

we drew a sample of size $100$ from a binomial($m = 2$,$p = 0.2$) distribution
and observed $76$ of the $x_i = 0$, $20$ of the $x_i = 1$ and $4$ of the $x_i = 2$

now as  $n → ∞$ the empirical distribution will look more and more like the binomial$(2,0.2)$ it was drawn from (why?).

I am guessing this is because of Law of Large No. (not sure if WLLN or SLLN). 
The empirical dist mean and variance will approach Binomial dist mean and variance??

my class notes has the following explanation:

For example, if $X_i ∼ Binom(2, 0.2)$ then for
$n = 100$,

$$  P \bigg( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{[X_i=0]}  \geq 0.76 \bigg) \simeq 0.007   $$
but for $n = 1000$
$$  P \bigg( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{[X_i=0]}  \geq 0.76 \bigg) \simeq 2.3\times(10^{-16})   $$

I understand the LHS in the probability function, that is the total proportion of $x_i = 0$, but I dont get why RHS is $0.76$, shouldn't it be $0.64\,$ (which is the probability of $x_i = 0$, from R code `dbinom(0,2,0.2))`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: How do you get 0.64? What is 'dbinom(0,2,0.2)'?

Comment: That is the probability of x=0, with m=2, and p=0.2, dbinom(0,2,0.2) is the R command that gives the probability.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the multinomial distribution, because you have 3 possible outcomes: $x_i \in \{0,1,2 \}$

Comment: No, it is Binomial, you are thinking of a Bernoulli trial, which only has two outcomes, Binomial is a sum of Bernoulli trials. Think of a single coin toss VS a series of coin tosses counting the heads. So in the above, m=2, means two Bernoulli trials. So xi∈{0,1,2}  refer to possible counts of heads in those two trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initial experiment with $n=100$ realizations of 
$X \sim Binom(2, .2)$ you got $X = 0$ 76 times, which is
larger than the expected 64 occurrences.

```
 dbinom(0, 2, .2)
 ## 0.64
```

This is a somewhat
surprising outcome because the probability of getting 76 or more 0's
is only 0.007, as your first displayed equation shows. (A slightly
different binomial computation verifies this claim.)

```
 1 - pbinom(75, 100, .64)
 ## 0.007013119
```

The question is
whether experiments with ever larger numbers $n$ of
realizations of $X \sim Binom(2, .2)$ will continue such
excessive numbers of 0's. So we check to see what we
could expect for $n  = 1000$ realizations. The answer is
that this degree of departure from what we expected is
then very unlikely indeed, as claimed in the second
displayed equation.

```
 1 - pbinom(759, 1000, .64)
 ## 2.220446e-16
```

The WLLN prohibits this kind of 'bad behavior' from persisting
as $n \rightarrow \infty.$

Perhaps a picture will help show the WLLN in action.
For $n = 1, 2, \dots 10,000$ the boundary between the light and
dark blue regions shows the running averages of instances with 0's
(ending very near 0.64);
the boundary between light blue and white shows running averages
with either 0's or 1's (ending very near 0.96).

[image]

The R code below (inelegant, but simple and correct) shows how the plot was made.

```
 n = 10^4;  x = numeric(n)
 for(i in 1:n) { x[i] = rbinom(1, 2, .2) }
 trace.0 = cumsum(x==0)/(1:n)
 trace.01 = cumsum(x<=1)/(1:n)
 plot(trace.01, type="h", ylim=c(0,1), col="skyblue", ylab="Running Avg.") 
 lines(trace.0, type="h", col="blue")
 abline(h = .64, col="red");  abline(h=.96, col="red")
```

Comment: Thanks BruceET, excellent exposition!

Comment: I am still not sure about the distinction between WLLN and  SLLN. 
 This is what I read from the picture, at n close to 10000, running averages of instances with 0's is slightly above 0.64, so it's possible to get a higher proportion of 0's as confirmed above $P(X > 760) > 0$:
Based on what I read in S. Ross' First course in Prob., SLLN states that above behavior only occurs finite amount of times for n very large, where as WLLN states this can occur infinitely many times for n large. Is this correct?

Comment: Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence or RVs 'converging' to $X$. WLLN says, $P(|X_i - X| < \epsilon) \rightarrow 1$, for any $\epsilon > 0.$ SLLN says $P(\omega: X_i(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)) = 1.$ Roughly speaking, in the former, there might be intervals where $X_i$ does not converge to $X$.Look around for a book or site with an example where WLLN holds and SLLN doesn't.